# Tamil language full-word search with .NET Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, tamil

I have a Grid filled with Tamil words and a search string. I need to implement a full-word search through the Grid records. I'm using .NET Regex class for that approach. It sounds pretty simple, what I used to do is:

`string pattern = @"\b" + searchText + @"\b"`.

It works as expected in Latin languages but for Tamil, this expression returns strange results. I have read about Unicode characters in regular expressions but that doesn't seem quite helpful to me. What I probably need is to determine where is the word boundary found and why.

As an example:
For the `"\bஅம்மா\b"` pattern Regex found matches in
அம்மாவிடம் and அம்மாக்கள் records but not in the original அம்மா record.

Comment: The last char is *‎0BBE  TAMIL VOWEL SIGN AA* and it belongs to the `\p{M}` Unicode class (combining marks). Use  `string pattern = @"(?<!\w)" + searchText + @"(?!\w)"` instead. Or if you want to avoid matching when inside base letters/diacritics, `string pattern = @"(?<![\p{L}\p{M}])" + searchText + @"(?![\p{L}\p{M}])"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the result is the same, unfortunately.

Comment: Please provide an example string and expected output. The regex above [only matches `அம்மா` as a whole word](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cw%29%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be%28%3f!%5cw%29&i=Regex+found+matches+in+%22%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be%e0%ae%b5%e0%ae%bf%e0%ae%9f%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%22+and+%22%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be%e0%ae%95%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%95%e0%ae%b3%e0%af%8d%22+records+but+not+in+the+original+%22%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be%22+record).

Comment: Strangely enough, some of online regex tester tools could return good result depending on the pattern but in the application itself, it's a constant failure. I should probably mention that I'm using MVS'17 and .NET Framework 4.6.

Comment: Here is a link to a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/izsyxo).

Comment: See https://ideone.com/izsyxo

Comment: Thank you for the sample Wiktor, it is working fine. I still have an issue, however, looks like something is wrong with the string I retrieve from a grid cell. If I'm specifying it manually in the code it works as expected but with the string retrieved from a cell, the result is null.

Comment: Copy/paste the exact string from the grid cell to the question.

Comment: No, to the *question*. Use formatting to show the real text. Note that `<` and `>` may disappear if you do not use `{}` code formatting.

Comment: Ok, I have had a peek at the raw contents of the question and you have `<Color = yellow>அம்மா</Color>`. So, `அம்மா` *is* a whole word here, and must be matched. Else, add the `(?!</Color>)` lookahead.

Comment: See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cp%7bM%7d%5d%29%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be%28%3f!%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cp%7bM%7d%5d%7c%3c%2fColor%3e%29&i=%22%3cColor+%3d+yellow%3e%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be%3c%2fColor%3e%e0%ae%b5%e0%ae%bf%e0%ae%9f%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%22+and+%22%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be%e0%ae%95%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%95%e0%ae%b3%e0%af%8d%22+%22%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be%22+record.)

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I have found the issue, you pattern works as expected now. It was a strange string conversion from some old code parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last char in "அம்மா" word is *‎0BBE  TAMIL VOWEL SIGN AA* and it is a combining mark (in regex, it can be matched with `\p{M}`).

As `\b` only matches between start/end of string and a word char or between a word and a non-word char, it won't match after the  char and a non-word char.

Use a usual workaround in this case.

```
var pattern = $@"(?<!\w){searchText}(?!\w)";
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cw%29%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BE%28%3F!%5Cw%29&i=Regex%20found%20matches%20in%20%22%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%22%20and%20%22%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%B3%E0%AF%8D%22%20records%20but%20not%20in%20the%20original%20%22%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BE%22%20record).

Here, `(?<!\w)` fails the match if there is a word char before `searchText` and `(?!\w)` fails the match if there is a word char after the text to find. Note you may also use `Regex.Escape(searchText)`  if the text can contains special regex chars.

Or, if you want to avoid matching when inside base letters/diacritics, use

```
var pattern = $@"(?<![\p{{L}}\p{{M}}]){searchText}(?![\p{{L}}\p{{M}}])";
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BM%7D%5D%29%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BE%28%3F!%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BM%7D%5D%29&i=Regex%20found%20matches%20in%20%22%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%22%20and%20%22%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%B3%E0%AF%8D%22%20records%20but%20not%20in%20the%20original%20%22%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BE%22%20record).

The `(?<![\p{L}\p{M}])` and `(?![\p{L}\p{M}])` lookarounds work similarly as the ones above, just they fails the match if there is a letter or a combining mark on either side of the search phrase.